# How to change the permissions of a read-only folder without privileges

Tags: windows-server-2008

So, I managed to put the wrong permission to a folder in Windows Server 2008 and ended up with all users having read-only privileges. How can I solve this permission issue?

Comment: you need to add some more details... but typically you just change the permissions on the folder. use an admin user to take ownership of the folder if you have to - and then change permissions.

Comment: It's not possible because all the users have read-only permissions. So when trying to edit the folders permission settings I get something like "you don't have access to this folder."

Comment: Are you an administrator on the machine in question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are NOT the owner and without privs using standard M$ utilities, I don't that that is a solvable situation.

In this case, You'll need the help of a user with either Local Administrator, or Domain Administrator access.  After that the steps are fairly clear: change owner, change permissions to allow the change in the ACLs, change the ACLs.

If of course you are the OWNER of the folder in question again the steps are fairly clear: change permissions to allow the change in the ACLs, change the ACLs.  As owner you CAN change the ACLs as long as you change yourself to allow the priv to do so.